# select with dynamic object options not working in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

See my plunker code i have created.  when i click toggle show button 2 times i should get selected item. This sample code is part of the component of general angular2 application

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div *ngIf="show"><select [(ngModel)]="selectedDeviceObj"  name="sel3">
    <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of deviceObjects">{{i.name}}</option>
  </select></div>
  {{selectedDeviceObj | json}}

  <br/><br/><br/>
  <button (click)="changeShow()">toggle show</button>
  `
  //directives: []
})
export class AppComponent {
  changeShow(){  
  this.deviceObjects = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}];
    this.show=!this.show;
  }

  show=true;
  title = "Angular 2 RC.4 - select";
  devices = 'one two three'.split(' ');
  selectedDevice = 'two';
  deviceObjects = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}];
  selectedDeviceObj = this.deviceObjects[1];
  //constructor() { console.clear(); }
  onChange(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedDevice = newValue;
    // ... do other stuff here ...
  }
  onChangeObj(newObj) {
    console.log(newObj);
    this.selectedDeviceObj = newObj;
    // ... do other stuff here ...

  }
}
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/RZ9uPMO095asHvrWYgvG?p=preview

Comment: I have created above plunker link to show my code. i couldnt add that to question body.